# How to close the parent dilaog after opened the browser from the message box when clicked on "OK" in the MessageBox

Tags: nsis

I am checking the required software before installing the installer, if the software is not present I am showing the MessageBox with "OK" button. When the user clicked
on "OK", it is navigating to the given URL to install the missing software. But here the issue is, the parent dialog is not closing when navigating from the Message box to the support page.

I tried different ways to close the parent dialog when the user clicked on "OK" button. Please suggest me if there is any way to close the dilaog.

```
 Function IsDotNetInstalled
    ClearErrors
    ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy\v3.0" "20319"
    IfErrors Error
    Goto End
    
    Error:
    
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP "Setup could not detect Microsoft .NET Framework v4.0 on this computer. $\r$\n$\r$\n Please install Microsoft .NET Framework v4.0 and run setup again. $\r$\n$\r$\n Click on OK to navigate to the Microsoft Support page" IDOK
    
    ExecShell open "https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=17718"
    
   SendMessage $HwndParent ${WM_QUIT} 0 0
   Abort
   Quit
    
    End:
    SendMessage $HwndParent ${WM_QUIT} 0 0
    Abort
    Quit
    FunctionEnd
```

I am calling the above function from the below section:

```
Section "RegistryTest (required)"
SectionIn RO

Call IsDotNetInstalled
ExecShell "" "$INSTDIR\Test.exe"

SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Abort` cancels the function you are in, try `SendMessage` before `Abort`. However, sending WM_QUIT is evil and should be your last resort. Applications are not generally designed to handle unexpected WM_QUIT messages.

Your question has no context so I don't know where this function is called. `Quit` might also work, depending on which callback it is called from and is always the better option when it works.

Comment: Hi @Anders, Sorry for the confusion. I am calling the function "IsDotNetInstalled" from the "Section. I Modified the original post with the updated code.

Comment: I have added "SendMessage" before "Abort" . But it is not closing the parent dialog when clicked on "OK" in the messagebox.

Comment: I said `Quit` followed by `Abort`, not the other way around! In this case when called from a `Section`, all you need is `Quit`. That `SendMessage` is a hack anyway and you should not send `WM_QUIT` because it is too harsh on applications.